# Making weight heatmap on recurring event in points layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, heat-map, weighted

I have a heatmap created on a points layer of deer-vehicle collision. Now, I want to weight the heatmap on the recurring of crash in the same area in different years.

I would give weight 0 if a point has no other point within 500m radius, 1 if a point has 1 point from the year before/after within 500m, 2 if a point has 1 point from year before and 1 point from year after, 3 if it has more, so that I can give more weight to that area in which the deer-vehicle collision are recurring every year, and not basing the heatmaps only on point density.

Now, I don't know how to create the new weight field without evaluating the points one by one, that would take a lot of time. Any suggestion? Of course I have a field with date and another with only the year in the points layer.

Comment: Create a 500 m buffer around the point and count the points that fall within it, create an attribute with this value.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm using QGis 3.22.3. If I create a buffer and count the point inside, then i count all the point, without distinguish the year....I guess

Comment: You can filter for the years